# How to make columns in Twitter bootstrap sass (alpha 4)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, mixins, bootstrap-4

i'm trying to use the make-col() mixin provided by SASS. http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/. What I'm trying to do is create two columns. With compiled classes, I'm table to do

And I get two divs that are floated next to each other in any size larger than `sm`.

In Bootstrap Sass (I'm using it part of React), when I do:

```
.row {
    @include make-row()
}
.left {
    @include make-col(3)
}
.right {
    @include make-col(9);
}
```

It does float the two next to each other, but when I shrink the screen down, the two don't block out. They remain floated. How do I get Bootstrap to mirror the above example when using mixins.

As an aside, from the documentation: `@mixin make-col($size, $columns: $grid-columns, $gutter: $grid-gutter-width)` - What exactly is `size`? Is it the number of columns? I'm confused because there is also a `$columns` variable.

Answer (score 9):

## Update

In **Bootstrap 4.1<**, there are mixins available for accomplishing grid system specific tasks. Those are the column related functions:

```
@include make-col-ready()
@include make-col($size, $columns: $grid-columns)
@include make-col-offset($size, $columns: $grid-columns)
```

---

## Example usage

**HTML**

```
<div class="example-container">
  <div class="example-row">
    <div class="example-content-main">Main content</div>
    <div class="example-content-secondary">Secondary content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SASS**

```
.example-container {
    width: 800px;
    @include make-container();
}
.example-row {
    @include make-row();
}
.example-content-main {
    @include make-col-ready();

    @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
        @include make-col(6);
    }
    @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
        @include make-col(8);
    }
}
.example-content-secondary {
    @include make-col-ready();

    @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
        @include make-col(6);
    }
    @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
        @include make-col(4);
    }
}
```

---

Sources:

- [Official Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#mixins)
- [Bootstrap Mixins Cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/anschaef/d7552885c0e1f127cf8830d3bbf6e4b1)

Comment: Works like a charm in latest stable 4.4. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

There is no detailed information on col mixins. From my experiments:

There are no mixins to create sm, md, lg col's in BS4. Instead one can extend the col-* classes.

Ex:

```
.product-gallery-list-item {
  @extend .col-md-6;
}
```

Comment: One has to be aware of the side effects of using the `@extend`

Answer (score -3):

I think you need a wrapper to your columns, or a parent container.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-9"></div>
</div>
```

Use the `make-row` mixin for that.

`$size` is used to control the width of your columns.

Hope it helps !

Comment: yup tried that, sorry edited my answer to reflect that